# Numbers in Devanagari

Tags: packages, languages, indic

### First question

Although the manual mentions that simple numbers would create Devanagari digits, somehow it is not working for me.

The way I use it in .dn file is:

```
{\dn || 1-23||\\}
```

Then passing .dn file through pre-processor generates the corresponding section in .tex file as:

```
{dn .. \rn{1}{\rs -\re}\rn{23}..}
```

And the output in .pdf still does not have numbers in Devanagari. It looks like:

[image]

### Second question

Including devanagari package, using

```
\usepackage{devanagari}
```

changes the font style of page number digits on the page of contents. What might be the reason behind this?

I tried to play around a lot to solve both the above issues, but was not able to solve them. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks [egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) for editing the post nicely! I did not have privileges of attaching images.

Comment: Finally found out what was going wrong. Should use:

    \dnnum \rn{1}

to get digit '1'. Completely my mistake to overlook this into the manual.